# Easily switching versions of Python in the command line interpreter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm grading projects written in Python. Some are written in Python 2, some in Python 3. I'm grading them through the command line for simplicity, but right now, projects written with Python 2-specific syntax won't work because the interpreter defaults to Python 3. Is there an easy way to designate which version of Python I want to use on the fly?

Comment: What platform are you on? The easiest answer is different between Windows and Unix, and the details are different between different Unix systems (e.g., on ARC Linux you have `python` vs. `python2`, on OS X you have `python3` vs. `python`, on some linux boxes you have `python3` and `python2` and can control which one is just plain `python`…).

Comment: @abarnert ARC Linux? D'you mean Arch Linux?

Comment: @Veedrac: Yes, thanks; ARC Linux is of course Linux for ARC processors, which is a whole different thing…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Python launcher on Windows:

```
C:\> py -2 some_script.py
```

If the script has the shebang such as `#!/usr/bin/env python3` then the launcher finds the appropriate Python version automatically:

```
C:\> py some_script.py
```

[Python launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) is included in the recent Python versions (since 3.3). You could install it separately otherwise.

You could also use [`vex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vex) utility with virtualenv:

```
$ vex py2 python some_script.py
```

that runs `python some_script.py` in `py2` virualenv.

On POSIX systems (Linux, OS X) if the script has executable permissions (`$ chmod +x some-script`) and it has a valid shebang such `#!/usr/bin/python` then you could run it directly:

```
$ ./some-script
```

Which python version (or even which program) will be used is defined by the shebang.

Comment: Beautiful, Python launcher is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use a [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

The second best way is to just setup your system to use `python` for python 2 and `python3` for python3.

Comment: Any suggested instructions for that 'second best way'?

Comment: It's system dependent, Mac, Windows, or Linux?

Comment: We'll need to do it on both Windows and Mac, actually.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the [conda](http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda) distribution which is available on all platforms. This makes easy to switch environments even with different python versions. For example:

```
conda create -n nameofpython2environment python=2    # creates a python 2 env
conda create -n nameofpython3environment python=3.3  # creates a python 3 env
```

Then to work in a given environment just do:

```
source activate nameofpython2environment
```

Once you are inside an environment you can install packages there:

```
conda install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aliases:

On windows its:

```
set "py2= path-to-python2-interpreter"
```

then call with:

```
%py2%
```

---

On Mac its:

```
alias py2='path-to-python2-interpreter'
```

then call with:

```
py2
```

---

On linux, its the same as on a Mac.

---

Note: these aliases wont save after you close the terminal window.
If you want them to save you need to put them in whatever config file your shell reads on start-up.

I only know the one for linux and its ~/.bashrc